# AS3:Move Objects in a curve path using as3 programming?

Tags: actionscript-3, bezier

I need to move many objects in a curve path across screen randomly. The objects start path and towards path also should take randomly. I had searched on google and finally i found one usefull tutorial to draw a curve. But i don't know how to move the objects using that curve path. But i am sure there would be some formula in as3 which has to use sin and cos theta. So please let me know if anybody have a solution for my problem. And also if i got any sample projects also would be very usefull for me.
    And the link  which i got to draw curve is as follows.
    http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/the-math-and-actionscript-of-curves-drawing-quadratic-and-cubic-curves/?search_index=4.

```
Thanks in advance.Immediate Help would be appreciated.
```

Comment: [This previous answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400642/attaching-movieclip-along-a-path-with-rotation-through-as3/9403446#9403446) may help you out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick'n'dirty would be using polar to cartesian coordinates(sin and cos) as you mentioned:

```
import flash.events.Event;

var a:Number = 0;//angle
var ra:Number = .01;//random angle increment
var rx:Number = 100;//random trajectory width
var ry:Number = 100;//random trajectory height


graphics.lineStyle(1);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,function (event:Event):void{
    a += ra;//increment angle            
    rx += a;//fidle with radii otherwise it's gonna be a circle
    ry += a;//feel free to play with these
    graphics.lineTo(225 + (Math.cos(a) * rx),//offset(225,200)
                    200 + (Math.sin(a) * ry));//and use pol to car conversion

    if(a > Math.PI) reset();//reset at 180 or any angle you like
});

function reset():void{
    trace('reset');//more values to tweak here
    a = Math.random();
    ra = Math.random() * .0001;
    rx = 20 + Math.random() * 200;
    ry = 20 + Math.random() * 200;
}
```

Random numbers need tweaking to get mostly rounder ellipses (rather than flatter ones), but the principle is the same.

If you don't mind using libraries, why not try [TweenLite's](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) [BezierPlugin](http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/plugins/BezierPlugin.html) or [BezierThroughPlugin](http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/plugins/BezierThroughPlugin.html). Should be easy to randomize start/end points.

Also you can check out the first part of this [older answer on quadratic,cubic and hermite interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205832/as3-function-for-extrapolating-points-on-a-spline-curve-or-hermite-curve-similar/7212012#7212012)

In my example I'm drawing a path, but of course, you could use those computed x,y coordinates to plug into a DisplayObject to move it on screen.

Comment: Thanks George, i will let u know after implement this. Thank you so much.