# curve tweening in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, runtime, tween

I want to tween a curved arrow from one point to another in as3. I mean this line,with a  arrow head, gets drawn from one point to another. this is to show the movement of say a nerve impulse from brain to another body part. I have tried shape tween but its not clean. I have tried using mask ,that again is tedious. I know how to draw by curveTo method. Is there a way that it can be tweened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this answer can provide you some help? [AS3 function for extrapolating points on a spline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205832/as3-function-for-extrapolating-points-on-a-spline-curve-or-hermite-curve-similar)
The answer also contains sample code and a DEMO on [wonderfl](http://wonderfl.net/c/pTgv) , courtesy of [George Profenza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89766/george-profenza)

Comment: Thanks again Claudius.

Comment: You very welcome, Jack! (but you know that I just re-posted George's answer, right? :-) )